# Connecting IBM Db2 to Watson Assistant

Tags: db2, websphere, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to connect IBM Watson Assistant to IBM Db2.
The use case is the user will input data through a channel and the data will be inserted in Db2.
I am under the impression that Node.Js would be needed and I am confused on how to get Data inputted into Db2 through the Watson Assistant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[this Assistant Db tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson)  shows how to call from Assistant to a cloud function and then into a database.

Although it is querying the database with information from Assistant, the Nodejs code could instead update the database with information from Assistant. You would have to write this update code for your use case.

I recommend the same architecture to work with your database.